# Does Tensorflow support Python 3.8.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, version, tensorflow2.0

I was just looking into Tensorflow for Python, and they say they support python version **3.5**-**3.8**. What I can't understand is, does "3.8" mean strictly **3.8.0** OR **3.8.x**(so 3.8.5 works)?

I know it can vary for different software.

I just want to make sure that IF 3.8.5 is supported, that I use that since it's a newer version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. I'm on Python 3.8.5 and using tensorflow==2.3.0.

Usually when a version is given as "3.5-3.8", it includes the patch versions as well. (Sometimes there could be issues that pop up but it's intended to include all patch version of the 'from' & 'to', inclusive.)

Answer (score -1):

I would think it works in 3.8.5, but it would be safer to use 3.8.0.